# Angular: when add remove Validators and update form status using CustomValidator...getting RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have requirements like if one field has value make other fields optional/remove required. I have tried like give below example using custom validator but if not use `updateValueAndValidity` form status not getting updated and it shows `invalid` and if I am using `updateValueAndValidity` getting an error  `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

How to solve this.

here is the custom validator code and [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-ddazqj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts):

```
EitherMobileOrWorkPhoneRequired(
    control: any
  ): ValidationErrors | null {
    const mobile:any = control.get('mobile');
    const workPhone:any = control.get('workPhone');
  
    const isNumberEmpty = (formGroup: AbstractControl): boolean => {
      const number = (<any>formGroup.get('number')).value;
      return number === undefined || number === null || number === '';
    };
  
    if (isNumberEmpty(mobile) && isNumberEmpty(workPhone)) {
      mobile.get('number').setValidators(Validators.required);
      

      workPhone.get('number').setValidators(Validators.required);
      

      return { required: true };
    } else if (isNumberEmpty(mobile)) {
      mobile.get('number').clearValidators();
     
    } else if (isNumberEmpty(workPhone)) {
      workPhone.get('number').clearValidators();
     
    }
      control.updateValueAndValidity();
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a continuous loop because you are calling `updateValueAndValidity()` while the validator is running.

This method:

> [Recalculates the value and validation status of the control.](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updatevalueandvalidity)

So when you call that, the `EitherMobileOrWorkPhoneRequired` logic re-runs over and over and over because you are triggering a recalculation of the validators.

Remove the `updateValueAndValidity()` call and it works as expected.

Validator update:

```
  EitherMobileOrWorkPhoneRequired(control: any): ValidationErrors | null {
    const mobile: any = control.get('mobile');
    const workPhone: any = control.get('workPhone');

    const isNumberEmpty = (formGroup: AbstractControl): boolean => {
      const number = (<any>formGroup.get('number')).value;
      return number === undefined || number === null || number === '';
    };

    if (isNumberEmpty(mobile) && isNumberEmpty(workPhone)) {
      return { required: true };
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Form now uses a single error message for the group, instead of one per control:

```
<b style="color:red;font-size:20px;"
  >1.Initial both required <br />
  2.When I enter mobile number , the work phone number becomes optional and vice
  versa
  <br />
  3.Form Status should be valid on submit
</b>
<hr />
<form [formGroup]="rootForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(rootForm.value)">
  <div *ngIf="!this.rootForm.valid" class="alert">
    <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="!this.rootForm.valid">
      A mobile or work phone number must be provided.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div formGroupName="mobile">
    <label>Mobile number</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="number" />
  </div>
  <div formGroupName="workPhone">
    <label>WorkPhone number</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="number" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If  remove ```updateValueAndValidity()``` ..Instantly control status is not getting updated and still it showing status as ```INVALID```.

Comment: @cjdevin Ive provided an update, but I am not 100% certain it meets your needs.

Comment: yes agree @Zze ```Form now uses a single error message for the group, instead of one per control``` but issue only is FormStatus ```!this.rootForm.valid``` is Invalid but that one needed valid.

Comment: @cjdevin `this.rootForm.valid` is true only when one, or both of the phone numbers is provided.

Answer (score 1):

The `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error is thrown because you're calling the `updateValueAndValidity()` function within the validator itself.

In Angular, it's recommended to avoid managing (remove/add) the validators from the validator function itself, and instead, you can do that outside the validator function, and keep the function only to check the validity of the control value and return `ValidationErrors` or `null`.

In your case, to handle the cross-controls validator on `FormGroup`, you can do the following:

- Remove the `Validators.required` validator applied to each control.
- Use the `*ngIf="this.rootForm.errors?.required"` to check if the form is invalid in component template, instead of checking each control error.
- Change the custom validator to be like the following:

```js
eitherMobileOrWorkPhoneRequired(control: any): ValidationErrors | null {
  const mobile: any = control.value.mobile?.number;
  const workPhone: any = control.value.workPhone?.number;

  if (isNumberEmpty(mobile) && isNumberEmpty(workPhone)) {
    return { required: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

And here is a working version of your StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-jucjpk

Comment: ```Remove the Validators.required validator applied to each control``` Not Possible because initially all control should be required.
```add/remove`` you can do that outside the validator function.Where and how?could you provide sample in same stackblitz.

Comment: Even in my answer, they are still required, but that's managed by the form validator not by the control validator. check again my working StackBlitz, please.

Comment: can you add ```Validators.required``` at control initialization ```ngOninit``` and also include form status in UI to show error.

Comment: I updated the StackBlitz to include the `Form Status: {{ rootForm.status }}` in the component template to display the form status. And the custom required validator is already added in ngOnInit.

Comment: Not only ```the custom required validator is already added in ngOnInit``` but also include control like this ```new FormControl('', [Validators.required])```..is it not possible?

Comment: Why do you need to add the `Validators.required` on controls also? this will add more complexity to the implementation and will require manual removing/adding of the validators. The current implementation handles all the cases you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242482/discussion-between-cj-devin-and-amer).